# How to push multidimensional array values in to single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here i am having one multidimensional array , using this array i have to merge the single array, i have tried in my point of view i have to use three foreach loop and then i have to push on one array,but my concern is if i am using foreach loop means my performance it will reduce,any one update my code with out for each loop or simplfied code

```
My Array



 Array
(
    "100" => Array
        (
            "class 1" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "ABC"
                    "1" => "CDE"
                )

            "class 2" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "F"
                )
        )

    "200" => Array
        (
            "class 3" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "G"
                )
        )

      )
```

> Expected Output

```
 Array
(
 "0" => "100"
 "1" => "ABC"
 "2" => "CDE"
 "3" => "F"
 "4" => "200"
 "5" => "G"
)
```

> I had tried like below

```
    <?php
$array = Array
(
    "100" => Array
        (
            "class 1" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "ABC",
                    "1" => "CDE"
                ),

            "class 2" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "F"
                )
        ),

    "200" => Array
        (
            "class 3" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "G"
                )
        )

      );
foreach($array as $firstKey => $firstVal){
    $mainArray[] = $firstKey;
    foreach($firstVal as $secondKey => $secondVal){
        foreach($secondVal as $thiredKey => $thiredVal){
             $mainArray[] = $thiredVal;
        }
    }

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mainArray);

?>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried. Also, using foreach isn't automatically bad. It's pretty fast, unless you're iterating through _a lot_ using it.

Comment: You want to "flaten" the array, you will find lots of examples for that on google.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson, please check i had updated what i tried

Comment: You still haven't told us why you don't want to use foreach, though.

Comment: @Prasanna you can achieve this without `foreach`; refer my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `foreach()`:

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($array as $key=>$arr){ // apply foreach on initial array

    $final_array[] = $key; // assign key first

    foreach($arr as $ar){ // now child is also array so iterate over it

        $values = array_values($ar); // get all values of child array

        foreach($values as $val){ // iterate over child array values

            $final_array[] = $val; //assign them one-by-one

        }

    }

}

print_r($final_array);// print final array
```

Output:- https://eval.in/1058692

***Without `foreach()`:***

```
$result = array();
array_walk($original_array, function($item,$key) use (&$result){
   $result[] = $key;
   array_walk_recursive($item, function($v) use (&$result){ 
     $result[] = $v; 
   });
});
print_r($result );
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/ECgdu

Comment: @Prasanna - Why this anti-`foreach`? Using `foreach` is even faster than using some `array_*`-functions in certain situations.

Comment: In my opinion, foreach would be your most quickest solution and will absolutely not affect your performance unless you have a lot, and I mean a LOT of iterations.

Comment: @Lachie  agreed with you. But i added other way too.(Just for OP's sake, i always prefer `foreach()`)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yep great answer. @Prasanna - if you did a benchmark test between the two you'll find that `foreach()` is actually much faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the multidimensional array like this

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($original_array, function($v) use (&$result){ 
   $result[] = $v; 
});
```

As you can see, your array will be processed into the closure/anonymous function and will flatten it as an end result.

Comment: I tried your code, but i am not getting my expected output

Comment: Please check my expected output from top

Comment: Of course, the indexes needs to be handled some other way. @Prasanna show me your code in this case. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using `foreach()` or `for()` loop by using `array_walk()` and `array_walk_recursive()`.

Here is the code;

```
// Your input array
$input = array (
    100 => array(
        "class 1" => array("ABC", "CDE"),
        "class 2" => array("F")
    ),
    200 => array(
        "class 3" => array("G")
    )
);

$result = array();
array_walk($input, function($val, $key) use (&$result){
    $result[] = $key;
    array_walk_recursive($val, function($v, $k) use (&$result){
        $result[] = $v;
    });
});
// Your result
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```